# Jump to position on click (access class from other Vue component)

Tags: javascript, vue.js

### Explanation of problem

If a user clicks on the login link the view shall jump down to the login window where a user can type in userdata.

I am aware how to do this within a single file using `document.getElementById('login-window').scrollIntoView()`

However, I have a project with various single Vue.js component files. The login-link is within one `"label"` component. But the actual login-window is located in another component called `"loginWindow"`, thus also the id / class `"login-window"` is stored in `"loginWindow"`.

I tried to grab the `"login-window"` element with `getElementById` within my `"label"` component, but I believe it cannot access it since it is in another component.

### This is the template code from "loginWindow"

```
<template>
  <LoginGrid class="login-window" :as-grid="true" :class="classes" autocomplete="off">
    <OCard class="login-card" :border="false">
      <div class="login-headline f-copy f-bold l-color-primary">{{ t('headline') }}</div>
      <!-- online state -->
      <template v-if="isLogged">
        <OButton color="secondary" @click="onClickLogout">{{ t('logout-label') }}</OButton>
      </template>
      <!-- offline state -->
      <template v-else>
        <div class="login-inputs">
          <LoginInput
            class="login-input-card-number" />
            ...
        </div>

        ...
        <OLink
          type="secondary"
          class="login-mode-link f-regular f-copy-small"
          :no-router="true"
          @click="onSwitchMode"
        >
          {{ modeLabel }}
        </OLink>
        ...
      </template>
    </OCard>
  </LoginGrid>
</template>
```

### Here is what I've tried exactly

Within my `"label"` component I have implemented this method with an else-statement:

```
export default {
  name: 'loginWindow',

  ...

  methods: {
    onClick() {
      if (this.isLogged) {
       ...
      } else {
          if (isBrowser) {
            document.getElementById("login-window").scrollIntoView();
          }
      }
    },
  },
}
```

So if the user is not logged-in, then `onClick()` it should scroll to the id of `"login-window"`.

However, this solution does not work. I get an error saying `"Cannot read property 'scrollIntoView' of null"`.

Any ideas how to do this with JavaScript within a Vue.js component?

Comment: Can you share your template of `id="login-window"` codes? and make sure `isBrowser` is true.

Comment: Hi Sajib, I edited it accordingly. Thanks for the recommendation. And yes, isBrowser is true.

Comment: It is preferable to access DOM using directives.. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/custom-directive.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`login-window` is Class not ID in your HTML. Try this:

```
document.querySelector(".login-window").scrollIntoView();
```